# Task complete with content data

Tags: jboss7.x, jbpm

I'm trying to access the task form via Rest api and complete the task form with user input results. All are working fine with Jbpm console. But i want to integrate it to my own application.Can anyone tell me how to complete task with form input data?

How to automatically render form inputs in jbpm console and save them?

Please can anyone answer this question?I can't go forward without solving this problem?

Comment: Could you specify the version you are using?

Comment: I use Jbpm 5.4, the users already registered  in the jbpm console can complete task via rest api. but new users can't log in to jbpm console. I think that is the problem. Can u tell me how to register new users in jbpm console?

Comment: It depends on the authentications realm you're using. What authentication realm do you use to already registered users?

Comment: Please can you little bit explain your question ?